# Remote debugging on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I am able to debug my EJB 3.0 app on my local JBoss (4.2.2 GA) in all cases, except when I put a break point in the actual bean. That just crashes the JBoss' JVM(1.5.14). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details of the crash? Especially if this happens to be an out of memory error or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post the JVM stack dump (it will be in the jboss/bin directory) which some here may have some insight into, but the first thing to do when the JVM crashes is to update to the latest revision, which is 20 in this case. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version did help, but unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: The stack dump is huge, i don't know how to paste more than 600 characters here. but here are the important parts of the error. and i have 3GB on the machine that i get this on, so should not be a memory issue. but i could be wrong.

Internal Error (5349474E41545552450E435050002E), pid=4892, tid=5500
Current thread (0x009946b8):  VMThread [id=5500]
Stack: [0x27c80000,0x27cc0000)
[error occurred during error reporting, step 110, id 0xc0000005]
VM_Operation (0x2cbdce48): generation collection for allocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x2ad175d0
Does this help?

Comment: If upgrading to the latest version fixed the problem, then 99% it is a bug in the JVM (debugging involves a lot of native stuff) that was fixed. You aren't going to be able to fix the problem, although I suppose there is an off-chance you could work around the problem. BTW, I'm no expert in reading these dumps, but others on SO may be, you could make a seperate question out of it.